# ¿A qué hace referencia "ella" en este fragmento?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

La cita es de "Cuando Sara Chura despierte" de Juan Pablo Piñeiro,

> Los tropicales cantan al alcohol con una mujer a su lado y el alcohol es la metáfora de la fugacidad de ese encuentro. En cambio yo le canto como un andino, porque es el elixir que despierta la memoria y por **ella** se hace insoportable la nostalgia. Beber es intentar olvidar recordando.

¿Qué significa *ella*? ¿Es la memoria, la mujer, como "it" o hace referencia a persona a fuera de la cita? Pregunto porque esta novela puede tener interpretaciones múltiples.

Yo soy un hablante de inglés que está aprendiendo español...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay desde luego cierta ambigüedad por el uso de pronombres, pero yo interpreto

> En cambio yo le canto (al alcohol) como un andino, porque (el alcohol) es el elixir que despierta la memoria y por **la memoria** se hace insoportable la nostalgia.

Podrías decir también

> En cambio yo le canto (al alcohol) como un andino, porque  es el elixir que despierta la memoria y por **esta** (la memoria) se hace insoportable la nostalgia.

No creo que se refiera a una mujer, porque se habla de ellas en plural en la oración anterior. No tiene sentido que en esta pase a referirse a una en particular. Si fuese "ella" una mujer, sería en todo caso "el **recuerdo** de una mujer", pero creo que no es el caso.

Del poco contexto que hay, yo deduzco que es la memoria la que hace insoportable la nostalgia, no una mujer.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Tanto con la respuesta como con la reflexión del escritor :)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Todo está aclarado para mi. :)

Comment: @DannyO'Brien You could mark the answer as accepted, then (and you can change this "accepted answer" mark to accept a different one if you receive new answers to your question(s)). Thank you for your contribution. I hope I see you around, using the site to improve your Spanish, which seems to be already really good.

Answer (score 1):

En literatura es común dejar elidido el sujeto intencionadamente en, al menos, dos casos diferentes, en caso de ambigüedad:

- Pretendes que el lector interprete el significado por su cuenta.
- Te refieres a ambas cosas, pero por el contexto queda mejor usar el singular.

En contraste a la anterior respuesta, yo interpreto *"la memoria de una mujer"*.

Comment: Lee detenidamente y veras que es simplemente "la memoria". En el texto se hace referencia al efecto del alcohol en la memoria. Nada que ver con "la memoria de una mujer"

Comment: Su comentario es muy interesante en conexión con las temas de la novela. Me siento que el lector tiene la capacidad para interpretar las palabras en su propia manera. Después de haber leído la novela, yo pensaba que "Sara Chura" representa tiempo andino/antiguo y posiblemente "ella" no mantiene la nostalgia, o algo sí. Preguntaba porque no quería hacer una suposición sin saber la gramática correcta.